# how to modify default response given by apache tomcat 9 for bad request , using spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, error-handling, tomcat9, bad-request

I have developed rest API using spring boot.
Now I am sending a request using malformed url like `http://localhost:8080/DD%/jhsj5/` from postman.
I am getting response as

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} 
    h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} 
    h1 {font-size:22px;} 
    h2 {font-size:16px;} 
    h3 {font-size:14px;} 
    p {font-size:12px;} 
    a {color:black;} 
    .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to modify the response like I have modified for NohandlerfoundException as below

```
{
    "status": 404,
    "message": "",
    "error": "Invalid url Path"
} .
```

but in case of malformed url line above   `http://localhost:8080/DD%/jhsj5/` , there is no exception thrown in my code.
so how to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

A [github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21257#issuecomment-745565376) was oppend for this and it contains the follwoing workaroud posted by sc-moonlight :

```
 @Bean
public TomcatWebSocketServletWebServerCustomizer errorValveCustomizer() {
    return new TomcatWebSocketServletWebServerCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
            factory.addContextCustomizers((context) -> {
                Container parent = context.getParent();
                if ( parent instanceof StandardHost) {
                    ((StandardHost) parent).setErrorReportValveClass("aaa.bbb.ccc.configuration.CustomTomcatErrorValve");
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public int getOrder() {
            return 100; // needs to be AFTER the one configured with TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer
        }
    };
}
```

and

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc;

public class CustomTomcatErrorValve extends ErrorReportValve{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomTomcatErrorValve.class);
    protected void report(Request request, Response response, Throwable throwable) {
        if  (!response.setErrorReported())
            return;
        LOGGER.warn("{} Fatal error before getting to Spring. {} ", response.getStatus(), errorCode, throwable);
        try {
            Writer writer = response.getReporter();
            writer.write(Integer.toString(response.getStatus()));
            writer.write(" Fatal error.  Could not process request.");
            response.finishResponse();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```